# MQTT | Publisher automatically disconnect and connect on his own

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

I use mosca (for node js) to create a MQTT server and MQTT (still node js) package to create publishers and subscribers. Everything work good except one thing: publisher reload automatically

I guess it may be due to incorrect mqtt.connect options. I read npm mqtt manual but still don't understand my mistake (or mistakes)

P.s. Sorry for my grammatical, I'm not an English speaker
UPD: i'm beginner :)

MQTT Server:

```
const mosca = require("mosca");
const MqttServer = new mosca.Server({
  port: 1884
});

MqttServer.on("clientConnected", function(client) {
    console.log('\x1b[0m', 'Клиент ' + '\x1b[32m' + client.id + '\x1b[32m' + ' подключен!' + '\x1b[0m');
});

MqttServer.on("clientDisconnected", function(client) {
    console.log('\x1b[0m', 'Клиент ' + '\x1b[32m' + client.id + '\x1b[31m' + ' Отключен' + '\x1b[0m');
})

MqttServer.on("ready", function() {
  console.log("Server MQTT Room1 running");
    
});

MqttServer.on("error", function(error) {
    console.log("error!");
    client.end();
})
```

Subscribe script:

```
const mqtt = require("mqtt");
const options = {
    clientId: 'mqtt_room1_SUB',
    clean: true
};
const client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://127.0.0.1:1884", options);

client.on("connect", function() {
  console.log("Connected");
  // connected = client.connected
  client.subscribe("room1/temp", { qos: 0 });
});
client.on("message", function(top, message) {
  console.log("Current temperature:", message.toString());
});

client.on("disconnect", function () {
    console.log('Server disabled.')
})
```

Publish script:

```
const mqtt = require("mqtt");
const options = {
    clientId: 'mqtt_room1_PUB',
    clean: true
};
const client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://127.0.0.1:1884", options);

client.on("connect", function() {
    console.log("Connected");
    setInterval(() => {
        var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
        client.publish("room1/temp", value.toString());
    }, 2000); 
});

client.on("disconnect", function () {
    console.log('Server disabled.');
});
```

[image]

Comment: The pub and sub code works just find with the mosquitto broker. The broker code you have provided is incomplete and won't run so it's hard to say what it wrong. Please update the broker code so it actually runs so we can debug some more. One possible option is that you have accidently run 2 copies of the publisher

Comment: All the code that I have shown is complete, all that I have deleted is the extra console logs. Also, the problem is that pub duplicates itself in some way, after which sub starts issuing two lines of data instead of one, and when closing one command line with this very pub, absolutely everything stops being published

Comment: The broker code provided will not run with the latest version of `mosca` it is missing a `backend` declaration. The important part is that clientIds must be unique. If you have multiple clients with the same client id (e.g. running 2 versions of the publisher) then they will kick each other off the broker. There is not enough information in the question to say why you have 2 versions running.